# C# Reading Serial data from sensor

Tags: c#

I want to make a GUI for my device to show the value of each sensor. My device send data with this format

`:1*895*123;
:1*987*145;`

`*` is use to separate data from sensors

`;` is for the end of data

`:` is for start of data in next loop

I have variables dot, Rx1 and Ry2 to storing the data and show it on label, but looks like my program didn't works.. here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string TestText, Rx1, Ry1, dot;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 2400;

        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }

    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestText = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        string[] nameArray = TestText.Split ('*');
        foreach (string name in nameArray)
        {
            dot = nameArray[0];
            Rx1 = nameArray[1];
            Ry1 = nameArray[2];
        }
    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = dot;
        posY.Text = Ry1;
        posX.Text = Rx1;
    }
        //this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }


}
```

I'm still new in c# and not so good with it.. so i need help. thanks before.

Comment: "didn't works" - in what way? what happened? what did you expect to happen? Also: `ReadExisting()` - are you checking to split messages correctly?

Comment: i want to get the sensor data and show it on my GUI.. but somehow, this far my GUI can show only 1 character at a time. and that's make i can't use it because the data was incorrect.

Comment: to make it clear.. i want to make some GUI for my Wii IR camera sensor. I have extracted the data using arduino and send the data like that format, which is 1 is for number of IR detected, 895 is the X position of the IR and 123 is Y position of the IR. now i just confuse how to collect that data stream and split it to put it on every variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're getting complete packets in the data received method? if not you'll need to buffer them up to be sure it's working properly.

You could try something like this.

```
// A buffer for the incoming data strings.
string buffer = string.Empty;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  // buffer up the latest data.
  buffer += serialPort1.ReadExisting();;

  // there could be more than one packet in the data so we have to keep looping.
  bool done = false;
  while (!done)
    {
       // check for a complete message.
       int start = buffer.IndexOf(":");
       int end = buffer.IndexOf(";");
       if (start > -1 && end > -1 && start < end)
       {
          // A complete packet is in the buffer.
          string packet = buffer.Substring(start + 1, (end - start) - 1);

          // remove the packet from the buffer.
          buffer = buffer.Remove(start, (end - start) + 1);

          // split the packet up in to it's parameters.
          string[] parameters = packet.Split('*');
          rx1 = parameters[0];
          ry1 = parameters[1];
          dot = parameters[2];

       }
    else
       done = true;
}
```

Comment: question, how do i call the data on parameter1,2,3 so i can show it on label? since parameter1,2,3 is not public i think..

Comment: You can simply ignore those if you want and set your class level strings Rx1, Ry1, dot.


rx1 = parameters[0];
ry1 = parameters[1];
dot = parameters[2];

Comment: I should also point out that if DataReceived is called multiple times on several threads at the same time, this code will not work. If that's the case then we can come up with a thread safe method instead.

Comment: i guess i find some bug.. the data that was transmitted is not stable. it always come with some random code and it effect when i try to parse it into int for another processing. what should i do.. i've try to set the baudrate higher at 9600 and still happen, but not often like when i use 2400

Comment: fixed by increasing delay time from my micro. now the next problem... i can't use the data for controlling my mouse or am i wrong input the variable? i make a modification from johnny lee's wiiWhiteboard source code, where i change ws.IRState.RawX1 into x1 `int.parse (Ry1)` and another wiimote reference. what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

If you getting just one chunk of data after reading. For example `:1*895*123;`

```
TestText = serialPort1.ReadExisting();//:1*895*123;
string[] nameArray = TestText.Split(new []{":", "*", ";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
label3.Text = nameArray[0];//1
posY.Text = nameArray[1];  //895
posX.Text = nameArray[2];  //123
```

and if you receive `:1*895*123; :1*987*145;`

```
var chunks = s.Split(new [] { ":", ";", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var chunk in chunks)
{
   string[] data = chunk.Split(new [] { "*" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   label3.Text = data[0];
   posY.Text = data[1];  
   posX.Text = data[2];  
}
```

But then in labels you just see latest chunk data, so you need store a list of your data. For example you can create class:

```
class chunkData
{
    public string dot;
    public string posX;
    public string posY;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
private List<chunkData> dataList = new List<chunkData>();
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   TestText = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
   var chunks = TestText.Split(new [] { ":", ";", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   foreach (var chunk in chunks)
   {
      string[] data = chunk.Split(new [] { "*" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      dataList.Add(new chunkData(){dot=data[0], posX=data[1], posY=data[2]})
   }
   //display dataList to DataGridView or other control
}
```

**EDIT**: here is what you can do if you receiving data symbol by symbol:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   string temp = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
   if(temp == ";") //OK we have end of data lets process it
      splitAndDisplay();
   else
      TestText += temp; 
}

private void splitAndDisplay()
{
   string[] nameArray = TestText.Split(new []{":", "*"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
     {
       label3.Text = nameArray[0];
       posY.Text = nameArray[1];  
       posX.Text = nameArray[2];
      }));
   TestText = "";
}
```

Comment: actually, the data will still continue until i disconnect my device or close the program. and it will loop with different data when my sensor sensing some changes

Comment: What is value of  `TestText` after `TestText = serialPort1.ReadExisting();`?

Comment: a single character at a time. if i use program from here, [link](http://csharp.simpleserial.com/) it will show like what i post, but when i do `posX.Text = TestText`, it will show 1 character and keep changing according to the stream.

Comment: Same result when using `serialPort1.ReadLine()`?

Comment: readLine will show the full line from `:` to `;` correctly, but it will come with error after that

Comment: there was error when start, `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'posY' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`